# Security issues for a Java program that is a consumer of streaming radio

Tags: java

Are there any security issues I should be aware of when opening a Socket connection with the url/port of a streaming radio station?

I have written some code to do this (no web stuff, just some Swing/awt and a Socket connection).

Comment: ... did you introduce any when parsing/using/receiving the stream's data? Per se, a socket connection is only data comming in - there might be problems as to what you expect it to be vs. what it actually is.

Comment: This is really too broad and undefined to be able to answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use [SSLSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLSocketFactory) instead of SocketFactory for your client server application. That way, the communication between the two will be totally encrypted. You can secure your client server app in less than a day, if you know basic Java. Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/samples/index.html).

Comment: the streaming host I am using is http, not https. So, can I really use an SSLSocket instead of Socket?

Comment: No, the server would need to support HTTPS.

Comment: The code in that tutorial doesn't look very safe. Also it predates the HTTP client.

Comment: Slapping TLS on does ***not*** secure a client. It merely ensures that it's very difficult to tamper with data between server and client.